# Olympiad question: How many permutations with no fixed letters does BHARAT have?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

We will say that a rearrangement of the letters of a word has *no fixed letters* if, when the rearrangement is placed directly below the word, no column has the same letter repeated.  For instance, HBRATA is a rearrangement with no fixed letters of BHARAT.  How many distinguishable rearrangements with no fixed letters does BHARAT have?  (The two As are considered identical.)

[image: The solution]

A p&c question is given with its solution which was asked in mathematics olympiad , but the solution is very tricky to understand so how will we understand the solution ?

Comment: Was this asked in PRMO?

Comment: Yes , correct , it was asked in PRMO.

Comment: Please type your questions rather than posting images since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom4 2$  ways = $6$ ways in which the two $A's$ are out of position.

The remaining $4$ *distinct* letters with $2$ of them (call them $X$ and $Y$) "in position"

We now apply [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), to find total permutations minus those with at least $X$ still in position minus at least $Y$ still in position *plus* both $X$ and $Y$ still in position (because we subtracted such cases twice), thus

$4!-3!-3!+2! = 14$ and multiply by $6$